# Not Showing Placeholder Image even when url in networkimage become's null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

GetPhotoUrlStream provide a stream of Url of Profile Photo (data['profilePhoto']) Stored in my Cloud Firebase FireStore. which then being utilized by networkimage to show the profilephoto(circular Avatar)

```
 class GetUserPhotoUrlStream extends StatelessWidget {
      final String documentId; // This is your User UID
    
      GetUserPhotoUrlStream(this.documentId);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        DocumentReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(documentId);
        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: users.snapshots(),
          builder:  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Image.asset('assets/images/NouserImage.png');
            }
    
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
    
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
            return  CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 80,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ClipOval(child: FadeInImage(placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/NouserImage.png'),image: NetworkImage("${data['profilePhoto']}"),),),
               
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

removeUserPhotoUrl update's the 'profilePhoto' to null which is being used by GetUserPhotoUrlStream.

```
  Future<void> removeUserPhotoUrl(BuildContext context) async
  {
    var user = _auth.currentUser;
    DocumentReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
     users.update({'profilePhoto':null}).then((_){
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
    await deleteUserImage(context);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

when the value of data['profilePhoto']  is made null using removeUserPhotoUrl it should show me placeholder image which is Provides an assetImage rather it gives an error

Error Message

```
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null
====================================================================================================
```

Also When app is HotReload or HotRestart The Error is Gone and it start Showing Me the PlaceHolder(Asset Image)

Please Help.I want to show Placeholder(Asset Image) as soon as the 'profilePhoto' becomes null

Answer (score 0):

Try this and also make sure that Your images is places inside pubspec.yaml

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Image.asset('assets/images/NouserImage.png');
                }
```

Comment: thanks for responding to the question but this did not work for me and the error remain's the same as in Cloud firebase firestore is not only having data for profilePhoto but also having other detail's such as which can't be null so `snapshot.hasData` will always be having some data